# How to let the VS2013 call stack show more functions

Tags: c++, mfc

In my MFC program, I need to parse a 1.2GB file.During debugging, every time the program near the completion of parsing,it will has an exception as follows:

> First-chance exception at 0x522C31CA (msvcr120d.dll) in LogDataTrans.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0003FA0C.

Here is the last function in call stack:msvcr120d.dll!memcpy(unsigned char * dst, unsigned char * src, unsigned long count) Line 188 Unknown.But other functions in the call stack are defined in mfc120d and user32.dll.I have changed the code from `memcpy(&_lrs.body[_lrs.lenBody], buf, l);` to

```
  try{
    memcpy(&_lrs.body[_lrs.lenBody], buf, l);
  }
  catch (...){
    ofstream f("memcpy.error");
    f << "memcpy.error";
  }
```

But the same problem occurred.Also,this memcpy function has been used many times before the exception occurs.
I can't find elsewhere my own code is wrong.So, I want to let the call stack show more functions to let me trace back to my own functions,not only functions provided by the system.The current call stack is this:

> msvcr120d.dll!memcpy(unsigned char * dst, unsigned char * src, unsigned long count) Line 188   Unknown
>       LogDataTrans.exe!AfxWinMain(struct HINSTANCE__ *,struct HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int)   C++
>       mfc120d.dll!_AfxDispatchCmdMsg(CCmdTarget * pTarget, unsigned int nID, int nCode, void (void) * pfn, void * pExtra, unsigned int nSig, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 77   C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID, int nCode, void * pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 373    C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CDialog::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID, int nCode, void * pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 85    C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2784 C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CDialogEx::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 290 C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam, long * pResult) Line 2108    C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2094  C++
>       mfc120d.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 282    C++
>       mfc120d.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 435 C++
>       mfc120d.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 299 C++
>       user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@24()  Unknown
>       user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()   Unknown
>       user32.dll!_xxxButtonNotifyParent@12()  Unknown
>       user32.dll!_xxxBNReleaseCapture@12()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_ButtonWndProcWorker@24()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_ButtonWndProcA@16() Unknown
>       user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()   Unknown
>       user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_IsDialogMessageW@8()    Unknown
>       user32.dll!_IsDialogMessageA@8()    Unknown
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::IsDialogMessageA(tagMSG * lpMsg) Line 193 C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::PreTranslateInput(tagMSG * lpMsg) Line 4590   C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 80 C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 275  C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::WalkPreTranslateTree(HWND__ * hWndStop, tagMSG * pMsg) Line 3363  C++
>       mfc120d.dll!AfxInternalPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 233  C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWinThread::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 777 C++
>       mfc120d.dll!AfxPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 252  C++
>       mfc120d.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage() Line 178   C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWinThread::PumpMessage() Line 900  C++
>       mfc120d.dll!AfxPumpMessage() Line 190   C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::RunModalLoop(unsigned long dwFlags) Line 4644 C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CWnd::CreateRunDlgIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd, HINSTANCE__ * hInst) Line 470   C++
>       mfc120d.dll!CDialog::DoModal() Line 633 C++
>       LogDataTrans.exe!CLogDataTransApp::InitInstance() Line 75   C++
>       [External Code] 
>     LogDataTrans.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26  C++

All these functions are not defined by me.

Comment: Is your program compiled in `Debug`?

Comment: If you call this `memcpy` from your code - make sure you provide valid size and valid pointers so `memcpy` doesn't write beyond destination buffer.

Comment: Enable the symbol server so you can get PDBs for these DLLs.  Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.

Comment: Please show the stack trace

Comment: Re: `I have changed the code from memcpy(...` - WHERE did you change this code? Is it your code or MS library? If it is yours - do you validate the parameters?

Comment: It is my own code,i found the pointer is not valid.But can you tell me how to show more functions in the call stack?Or it's not necessary.@MichałWalenciak